# Decimal Number Format Conversion Java

Tags: java, decimalformat

Is there a **DecimalFormat** pattern to convert 12.30 to 1230, 
or 12.321 to 12321?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a conversion, that's multiplying by a factor that differs between your examples.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, what is the best way to achieve it without multiplying?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to assume that 101 == 10.1 == 1.01 but 101 != 101.0

Comment: Convert it to String and replace the "." with nothing? :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is not about equalities but just number patterns.

Comment: @Yasothar playing with patterns can be fun, but playing with numbers which don't make any sense is dangerous.  I see this too often in professional life, and I suggest you avoid doing this where ever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will work for you :

```
double d2 = 1234.567;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(d2).replaceFirst("\\.", ""));
```

*Output:*

> 1234567

Comment: Thanks for answering. 1234.567 is fine. but I require 1234.00 to be 123400. is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert to string and remove the . something like..

```
    Double d = 50.53;
    int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(d).replaceAll("\\.", ""));
```